# Responsive + Angular: Change behavior from routing to simply refresh data when screen is large?

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a little application to manage messages. Such application has two panels on big screens: a sidebar with the messages list and a panel with the message details: [ ][    ]. But in case the screen is small (smartphone) and just because we want it to be responsive, the sidebar is the only thing shown and when you click on a message the details are displayed hiding the sidebar.

With Angular, the last approach is quite easy doing some routing and it works very well. My problem comes **when the screen is big** enough to accept both panels together, as I want Angular to still control the flow but not hide/show any panel as **I want both views visible**.

Is there a way to go routing (one view at a time) with Angular when the screen is small but change the behavior when the screen is big to show the two views at a time?

By the way, I'm using Bootstrap to control the responsiveness and that's working quite well (the panels hide/show depending on screen size), I'm just worried about how am I going to handle this with Angular now.

**Examples**

Just to see if I can explain myself better, this is what I want it to be when screen is big enough: http://plnkr.co/edit/WuN08Q?p=preview (make sure you make the preview screen big enough to see it, click on a message, and then resize to smaller size to see how the details hide)

And this when it's small: http://plnkr.co/edit/UL1OpXjzEcCU9722lpA9?p=preview

First example has two panels visible and one of them is hidden when screen becomes small, second example uses two views and works as I want it when screen is small. Now **what I want is to make it behave like first example when screen is big enough and like second when it's small**.

Thank you Angular wizards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but one solution building upons Jonathan Hair's answer is contained in a fork of you original plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/chdn6XDpdnqaay3VfOqI?p=preview

This solution is not preferred because you end up having to refresh when you break across your sm / large barrier (in this case 768px width) in order to get the expected rendering behavior.

I think a better approach to this problem is to not use routing. (Which is precisely what I did for your "Big view.")

As an example, here is a unified scope that utilized the bootstrap responsive utility and builds off of Jonathan's size detection.  As the screen is resized, it should follow the expected behavior.  No routing necessary.

http://embed.plnkr.co/b7sSyDjRLSRrJF29l01d/preview

Comment: Thanks! Your second example is what I was looking for :D Maybe not exactly what I wanted as it doesn't refresh automatically but close enough and that would work just fine. So thank you a lot, even though Jonathan was giving me some leads and you too I was still not able to see how to do it myself. Giving a +1 to Jonathan though as he also helped.

Comment: The second example should refresh.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function in the templateUrl section for routing in you app config and change the templateUrl based on current window size. I dare say you would have the same functionality in the controllers so changes to just the templateUrl should suffice.

NOTE: In my example below I have just placed the window size logic where needed, you would put this somewhere else in your app like a helper file or a service instead.

Example
http://plnkr.co/edit/udDlJT?p=preview

Comment: I have the feeling that your example is just resizing one of the views? I'm doing that already using Bootstrap. What I was asking is how to display two views at a time when screen is large and only one when it's small. Your example shows only one view all the time, I don't see how does that solve my doubt I'm afraid :S

Comment: Sorry I assumed that your second view (message list) is always viewable and would just hide on click event when showing main mesaage. I'll update my example.